# C# - How can I disable gridview from clicking if a certain button was clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this `OnRowDataBound` method below that makes a `GridView` clickable. How can I make the `GridView` not clickable if a certain button was clicked?

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
            {
                
                //Makes a grid clickable or not
                if (!enableGridSelection)
                {
                    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                    {
    
                        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(grdRecentCases, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
    
                    }
                }
             }

public void Button1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ...

}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use javascript to disable the GridView on the button click. If the button click is doing some server side job then you use AJAX on the button click to perform this task.

Comment: Are you looking to disable the current row that you clicked on in the GV, or simple disable all row clicks (the ability to row click on any row?).